# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value XXX in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to pass data class using parcelable but I got this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=,
```

**hear is my data class in splash activity viewmodel**

```
@Parcelize
data class SplashScreenState(
    val error: Boolean = false,
    var completed: Boolean = false,
    val response: @RawValue Response<RegisterDto>?=null
) : Parcelable
```

**RegisterDto**

```
@Parcelize
data class RegisterDto (
    @SerializedName("has_payment"    ) var hasPayment    : Int,
    @SerializedName("weight"         ) var weight        : Int,
    @SerializedName("wellness_goal"  ) var wellnessGoal  : Int,
    @SerializedName("has_validation" ) var hasValidation : Int,
    @SerializedName("user_id"        ) var userId        : Int,
    @SerializedName("name"           ) var name          : String,
    @SerializedName("goal_weight"    ) var goalWeight    : Int,
    @SerializedName("eating_habit"   ) var eatingHabit   : Int,
    @SerializedName("birthdate"      ) var birthdate     : String,
    @SerializedName("token"          ) var token         : Token,
    @SerializedName("avatar"         ) var avatar        : String
) : BaseDataResponse(),Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class Token (
    @SerializedName("token_type"    ) var tokenType    : String,
    @SerializedName("scope"         ) var scope        : String,
    @SerializedName("access_token"  ) var accessToken  : String,
    @SerializedName("expires_in"    ) var expiresIn    : Int,
    @SerializedName("refresh_token" ) var refreshToken : String
) : Parcelable
```

**splash activity**

```
 val response = viewModel.state.value
        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("isTokenExist", isTokenExist)
        intent.putExtra("response", response)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
```

**MainActivity**

I get isTokenExist value and response like below in MainActivity

```
  val isTokenExist: Boolean = intent.getBooleanExtra("isTokenExist", false)
        val refreshTokenResponse: SplashScreenState? = intent.getParcelableExtra("response")
```

what is the problem ? I implemented **Parcelable** to my SplashScreenState data class and as you can see I implemented **Parcelable** to RegisterDto data class. I think I've added it wherever I need to add, can you help me that issue ?